# Linear approximation of a system described by a logarithm - how?

Tags: linear-systems, dynamic-system

The system described by a logarithm of any base, let's call it $y(t) = \ln(t)$, is non-linear.

- Is it possible, by any means (transforms, operators etc.), and for small values of $t$ (for example, $t>0$ and $t\leq 0.5$), to obtain a linear approximation of the system (in such $y(t_1+t_2) = y(t_1)+y(t_2)$) with an acceptable percentage error (i.e, up to $5\%$)?
- Is there any log base more suited to perform the task?

Answer (score 1):

Concave functions like $\sqrt{\cdot}$ or $\log{(1+\cdot)}$ may emulate nonlinear system behavior like saturation. They are although used as companding methods, such as the [$\mu$-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm#Comparison_with_A-law) (or the [A-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm)):

$$ x\to \mathrm{sgn}\,x\frac{\log{(1+\mu|x|})}{\log{(1+\mu)}}\,. $$

This can be used prior to quantization for signals with high-dynamics, and allows one to use uniform quantization and maintain a similar amount of relative errors for weak as well as strong signals (see for instance [Digital filtering using logarithmic arithmetic](https://doi.org/10.1049/el:19710039) (I glad to discover this work by Nick Kingsbury).

For telephony, people developed segment ("piecewise linear", but actually piecewise affine to be correct) companding versions of such laws, for instance H. Kaneko, "[A Unified Formulation of Segment Companding Laws and Synthesis of Codecs and Digital Compandors](https://doi.org/10.1002/j.1538-7305.1970.tb01843.x)". Basically, $\log(x+y)$ can be approximated by some affine law in its proper interval. I am aware of such approximations  for square roots: if $a\ge b$, then for instance with about 4% precision:

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sim 0.96a+0.4b  $$

yet I have to check for logarithms. In the same framework, as already said by @ben, if $a$ is a fixed quantity:

- if $a>b$, then $\log(a+b)\sim b/a+\log a$

which is  an affine approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question in its current formulation is 'no', it's not possible. The reason is that for any $t>0$, I can make $t$ sufficiently small such that the error of a linear approximation becomes arbitrarily large. Note that $\lim_{t\to 0}\log(t)=-\infty$.

So you have to define a positive lower bound for $t$ in order to be able to come up with a reasonable approximation on an interval $t\in[a,b]$, $0<a<b$. It's easy to find the coefficients of a linear function $f(t)=c_1t+c_2$ that represents a best least squares fit of $g(t)=\log(t)$ on that interval. You have to judge for yourself if such an approximation is good enough for your application.

If as an example you consider the interval $t\in[0.01,0.5]$ you might end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! 
I'm aware that for arbitrary small values of t approaching zero, the error becomes too large, so I should have made it clear in my question :). Sorry for this! 
 
Also, $f(t)=c_1t+c_2$, although linear (in some sense...) is not a linear system such as $f(t_1+t_2) = f(t_1)+f(t_2)$.

Comment: @HugoChrist: That's right, but if $f(t)=ct$ is the only acceptable option, then you won't get any reasonable approximation for small values of $t$. I'm not sure what exactly it is that you want or expect.

Comment: I expect to confirm there is no trivial way to do I wan't (in the sense it is impossible or really really hard...). My best option right now is to work with $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ and see if I can get the work done with a variable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(1+x) \approx x$ for small values of $x$.

Therefore, you should try to do a variable substitution to map your $\ln(t)$ equation to a form akin to $\ln(1+x)$.

Obviously, this will not work if $t$ is really close to $0$, can you guess why?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)
This approach is what I'm already considering to work with. Just asked hoping for something different and maybe more efficient (i.e, an linear approximation with less error).  .

Comment: @HugoChrist You could try a Taylor expansion or Chebyshev polynomials with any degree of accuracy you need.